# Using a comb filter when peaks are not equidistant

Tags: matlab, filter

I am trying to use a comb filter to clear up my spectra, I would like to get a spectra with peaks that are 20% or more of the magnitude of the predominant peak to be included ad zero elsewhere however I m not sure how to specify this with my comb filter as most of the examples shown in the documentation seem to be for peaks that are equidistant apart. I am using

```
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(x,'MINPEAKHEIGHT',20/100*max)
```

how can I then apply a comb filter correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me. I modified the example from the doc (taken [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html)) in which peaks are not equidistant, and it does not consider peaks which are less than 20% the height of the maximal value. Maybe I did not get your question right though. Anyhow here is the code:

```
clc
clear

x = linspace(0,1,1024);
Pos = [0.1 0.13 0.15 0.23 0.25 0.40 0.44 0.65 0.76 0.78 0.81];
Hgt = 4*[4 5 3 1 5 4.2 2.1 4.3 3.1 5.1 0.6];
Wdt = [0.005 0.005 0.006 0.01 0.01 0.03 0.01 0.01 0.005 0.008 0.005];
PeakSig = zeros(size(x));
for n = 1:length(Pos)
    PeakSig = PeakSig + Hgt(n)./(1 + abs((x - Pos(n))./Wdt(n))).^4;
end

[pks,locs] = findpeaks(PeakSig,'MINPEAKHEIGHT',20/100*max(Hgt(:)));

%pks = pks/max(pks(:))

plot(x,PeakSig/max(pks(:))), 
hold on
%  Offset values of peak heights for plotting
plot(x(locs),(pks/max(pks(:))+0.01),'k^','markerfacecolor',[1 0 0])
line([0 x(end)],[0.2 0.2],'Color','k','LineWidth',2);
hold off
```

[image]

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Just to check, this code will then zero out the other parts of the spectra? my original spectrum is very noisy and I want to zero it out and then plot a new spectrum that just includes these peaks. I would also then like to retain the values so I can use ifft to return to the time domain